# How to Play Two Videos Simultaneously in a UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ipad, video, uiwebview, ios

I'd like to play two videos at the same time from an HTML page in a UIWebView.  By default any playing video is stopped when another is started.  This happens even if the two videos live in different web views.

Is there a way to force continued play for the first video?

Answer (score 2):

You can only play one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible yet (Mar 15, 2017)

See ref. from Apple Developer website under section ["Multiple Simultaneous Audio or Video Streams"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html)

Answer (score -1):

just make two webviews with interface builder or coding on the same window or view and then u can do differnt things with both of them ..
  but u have to take two webviews on diffent side of screen  ,u cant take one web view over another

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work.  He even said it in the original question - "This happens even if the two videos live in different web views"